# What tools do I need to automate my Drupal workflow?

Tags: 7, deployment

What tools do I need to automate the following tasks:

**Project setup**

1. Generate project wide password
2. Setup prod domain and dev and stage subdomain on server
3. Create user with access to /bin/bash/
4. Add public keys
5. Change open_basedir and increase memory limit
6. Delete files in document root
7. Initialize Git repo on Git hosting
8. Clone Drupal Repo Recursively
9. Add .gitignore (including Mac, Drupal and SASS specific paths)
10. Create Zen/Omega Subtheme
11. Create drushrc.php & aliases.drushrc.php
12. Commit changes
13. Create dev branch
14. Add Git remote and Push the branch master to it
15. Create databases for prod, stage and dev
16. Run site-install
17. Setup cron
18. sql-sync and rsync from prod to stage and dev
19. Fix file permissions

Comment: This is a rather broad question. It could be better to focus on a specific part.

Comment: I removed the deployment and sync question.

Answer (score 4):

The [quickstart project](http://drupal.org/project/quickstart) will handle almost all of these tasks.  It is basically a preconfigured drupal development environment that you run in a virtual machine.

If you wanted to install the tools locally, you can do almost everything in your lists with [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) & make.